# How to promisify a parent class' class method to use in child class async-await method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, callback

I have a childClass and limited access to the parentClass. Within one of the childClass methods I need to invoke a parentClass method, `getToken()`. `getToken()`, and the rest of the parentClass, is written using callbacks. The child class is written with promises and async-await.

I know that's messy but this is the only spot where there are issues right now and this is what we need to do.

Example of issue

```
...
try {
    // getToken is not promisified yet so it doesn't work
    let tokens = await this.getToken();
    refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token;
}
...
```

Can I make a custom "promisifying" function? Something like,

```
// This isn't correct even if the idea were ok
async promisify(function) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   function((err, data) => {
     if (err) reject(err);
     else resolve(data);
   })
 })
}
```

Then in my code write:

```
...
try {
    // getToken is maybe promisified
    let tokens = await this.promisify(this.getToken());
    refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token;
}
...
```

Or would it looks something like

```
const util = require('util');
const asyncGetToken = util.promisify(parentClass.getToken);

...
try {
    let tokens = await asyncGetToken();
    refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token;
}
...
```

If so, would I have the right instance of the childClass to work with?

I know that's messy but thanks for any tips.

Comment: Your "*custom "promisifying" function*" isn't actually that far off, the only issues with it are that `function` is a keyword so you need to rename your parameter and that the `async` is unnecessary.

Comment: "*Would I have the right instance of the childClass to work with?*" - no. You would have to use `await promisify(this.getToken.bind(this))` though, or with the `util.promisify`'d version `await asyncGetToken.call(this)`.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code (or at least the interface definition/API documentation) of that "parent class"

Comment: Assuming the parent method is a standard nodejs asynchronous callback calling convention, you just use `utils.promisify()` on it and then probably `.bind()` to put the instance back on.